# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') in React JS

Tags: reactjs

These are my error coding, `propApptData.doctor` values are `Dr X|Dr Y`. I want to split the `propApptData.doctor` values and then put them in the `resource`, after that I reload the webpage and go to trigger this function, the page cannot show anything.

```html
if (propApptData !== undefined && preDoctor !== true) {
      const doctors = propApptData.doctor.includes("|") ? propApptData.doctor.split("|"): propApptData.doctor;
      setDoctorDetailList([...doctorDetailList, { resource: doctors }]);
      setPreDoctor(true)
    }
```

In the other function If the value just does not include `|`, just 1 doctor name, the function can be work if using below coding:

`propDoctorName` value is `Dr.X`

```html
if (propDoctorName !== undefined && preDoctor !== true) {
      setDoctorDetailList([...doctorDetailList, { resource: propDoctorName }]);
      setPreDoctor(true)
    }
```

The error result is shown below:

[image: img1]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

`[Update - 1 ]`

What I have tried just now, the doctor list cannot split into array like below picture:

```html
if (propApptData !== undefined && preDoctor !== true) {
      const doctors = propApptData.doctor ? propApptData.doctor.split("|"): [propApptData.doctor];
      setDoctorDetailList([...doctorDetailList, { resource: doctors }]);
      setPreDoctor(true)
    }
```

[image]

[Updated -2]

[image: img3]

[Updated -3]

[image: img5]

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. `propApptData.doctor` is *null* or *undefined*, at least for a moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

propApptData.doctor is undefined to solve it you can add ? mark like this`propApptData.doctor?.includes("|")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it, but cannot split in the doctor list. Can you help me to see? Thanks

Comment: i think you have to check if `propApptData.doctor` is undefined or not in the if clause `if (propApptData && propApptData.doctor  && !preDoctor)` like this. tell me if it works.

Comment: if (propApptData && propApptData.doctor  && !preDoctor) this one can. So the next step how to split these 2 doctor name in the doctor list (I have shown in my question below)

Comment: `if (propApptData && propApptData.doctor  && !preDoctor) {
      const doctors = propApptData.doctor.includes('|') ? propApptData.doctor.split("|"): [propApptData.doctor];
      setDoctorDetailList([...doctorDetailList, { resource: doctors }]);
      setPreDoctor(true)
    } ` does this work?

Comment: Yes. It is work. Just only cannot split each into doctor lists. Can you see my latest update in my question picture (Updated - 1)?

Comment: this function should work fine, I think the problem is in your jsx return area. can you make a screenshot or the code when you are mapping the resource in `doctorDetailList ` ?

Comment: Yup. Updated in my question already (Updated -2)

Comment: the resource is an array in `doctorDetailList ` . the array of doctors name that we split them with "|". if you want to show doctors name with spacing between their names you can use `join(" ")` operator. like this `{data.resource.join(" ")}` but I might misunderstand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I using this method {data.resource.join(" ")}, but the result is still remain same. Can see my update question (Updated - 3)

Comment: if you want implement a list of doctors to be shown you have to change your state when you want to add the doctors after you split their names.
` setDoctorDetailList([...doctors ]);`. if you add doctors in in an object with resource key and when you map through `doctorDetailList` doctors name will be repeated every row. idk doctorDetailList's values btw. I only know you have `{ resource: doctors }` at the end of doctorDetailList.

Comment: Okay. I think I should write another question about this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404650/array-map-method-cannot-show-properly-data-in-the-list

Hi @amin keshavarzi, I have created a new question on this ticket. If you can help can see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error self-explanatory, `propApptData.doctor` is undefined. To void these kinds of errors in the future, you can use the optional operator or assign a default value using the nullish operator or logical OR operator.

```js
// Optional operator
const doctors = propApptData.doctor?.includes("|") ? propApptData.doctor.split("|"): propApptData.doctor;

// Nullish Operator
const doctors = (propApptData.doctor ?? "" ).includes("|") ? propApptData.doctor?.split("|"): propApptData.doctor;

// Logical Or
const doctors = (propApptData.doctor || "" ).includes("|") ? propApptData.doctor?.split("|"): propApptData.doctor;
```

You can read more from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).