# Array map() method cannot show properly data in the list

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping

I have a problem to implement a list of doctors to be shown I have to change your state when you want to add the doctors after you split their names.

If I add doctors in an object with a resource key and when I map through doctorDetailList` doctors name will be repeated every row.

Below is my coding:

**Show the existing doctor's name in the doctor's list**

```html
if (propApptData && propApptData.doctor  && !preDoctor) {
      const doctors = propApptData.doctor ? propApptData.doctor.split("|"): [propApptData.doctor];
      setDoctorDetailList([...doctorDetailList, { resource: doctors }]);
      setPreDoctor(true)
      console.log(doctors.length)
    }
```

**Add doctor**

```html
const addDoctor = () => {
    var test = 0;
    doctorDetailList.forEach((list) => {
      if (list.id === searchDoctorName.id) {
        test++;
      }
    });

    if (test === 0) {
      setDoctorDetailList([...doctorDetailList, searchDoctorName]);
    }
  };
```

**Mapping**

```html
{propApptData !== undefined && (
                      <ListGroup>
                      {doctorDetailList.map((data, index) => (
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                          {data.resource}
                          <CloseButton
                            variant="link"
                            id={data.id}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                              setDoctorDetailList(
                                doctorDetailList.filter(
                                  (doctor) => doctor.id !== data.id
                                )
                              );
                            }}
                          />
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                      ))}
                    </ListGroup>
                    )}
```

**Formik**

```html
const formik = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: apptData || initialValues,
    validationSchema: AppointmentSchema,
    onSubmit: (values, { setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
      setSubmitting(true);
      enableLoading();

      var joinDoctors = doctorDetailList
        .map((data) => {
          return data.resource;
        })
        .join("|");

      checkUnavailableOrganizerSlot(
        formatServerDateTimeString(apptCheckingStartDate),
        formatServerDateTimeString(apptCheckingStopDate),
        joinDoctors
      )
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.isAvailable === true) {
            if (propApptData === undefined) {
              newAppointment(
                moment(selectedDate).add(8, "hours"),
                icpassport,
                values.reason,
                joinDoctors,
                values.type,
                values.location,
                values.priorityID,
                values.rootCause,
                values.nextAction,
                newPatient === true ? name : null,
                newPatient === true ? phone : "",
                values.estimatedTime,
                0
              )
                .then((res) => {
                  disableLoading();
                  setSubmitting(false);
                  props.close();
                  props.reloadList();
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                  disableLoading();
                  setSubmitting(false);
                  if (e.response && e.response.data) {
                    e.response.data.map((error) => {
                      setErrorType(error.data);
                      setErrorMessage(error.error_message);
                      setOpenNotificationPopup(true);
                      return "";
                    });
                  }
                });
            } else {
              updateAppointment(
                propApptData.id,
                joinDoctors,
                values.type,
                values.location,
                values.rootCause,
                values.reason,
                values.nextAction,
                propApptData.queueNumber,
                values.priorityID,
                values.status,
                propApptData.appointmentDate,
                propApptData.icPassport,
                propApptData.reminder,
                propApptData.treatmentPlannerID,
                propApptData.refID,
                propApptData.isCall,
                propApptData.createdBy,
                propApptData.createdDate,
                propApptData.username,
                "0:" + propApptData.duration + "," + propApptData.appointmentType,
                propApptData.patientComplaint,
                propApptData.priorityID,
                propApptData.locationID + "," + propApptData.location,
                propApptData.doctor,
                propApptData.statusID + "," + propApptData.statusDesc,
                propApptData.remark,
                propApptData.nextAction,
                propApptData.removed,
                values.estimatedTime
              )
                .then((res) => {
                  disableLoading();
                  setSubmitting(false);
                  props.close();
                  props.reloadList();
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                  setSubmitting(false);
                  disableLoading();
                });
            }
          } else {
            disableLoading();
            setSubmitting(false);
            formatSnackbar(
              res.data.resource +
              " " +
              intl.formatMessage({ id: "GENERAL.NOT_AVAILABLE" }) +
              " " +
              formatDateTimeStringAsDateTime(res.data.startDate) +
              " - " +
              formatDateTimeStringAsDateTime(res.data.stopDate) +
              ".\n\n" +
              intl.formatMessage({ id: "GENERAL.PLEASE_RESCHEDULE" }),
              "error"
            );
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log("fail", e);
          setSubmitting(false);
          disableLoading();
          formatSnackbar(
            intl.formatMessage({ id: "GENERAL.APPOINTMENT_FAIL" }),
            "error"
          );
        });
    },
  });
```

What I have tried:

The resource is an array in doctorDetailList  . the array of doctors name that I split them with "|". if I want to show doctors' name with spacing between their names I try to use join(" ") operator. like this {data.resource.join(" ")} , but it cannot work to show each doctor name in the doctor list.

My error result, it will show 2 times and the 3 doctor name combined together. If normal results appear 1 time and separate 3 doctor names in the doctor list:

[image: img1]

If I add more doctor name, the result show like below, it will appear two times, if normal just appear 1 time if I click add button:

[image: img2]

I want the expected result like the below picture:

[image: img7]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What is structure of doctorDetailList?

Comment: i think you should post your entire code.

Comment: @MortezaM I have updated on my question

Comment: @VMT Kindly view my updated question. Thanks

Comment: hello again, `const doctors = propApptData.doctor.includes('|') ? propApptData.doctor.split("|"): [propApptData.doctor];
      setDoctorDetailList([...doctorDetailList, ...doctors]);` I do not know about the whole logic but if you want to add doctors name in order to show the each row you have to add them like this `setDoctorDetailList([...doctorDetailList, ...doctors]);`. and in JSX return when you map doctorDetailList instead of `{data.resource}` you show `{data}` which is doctor's names.

Comment: {data.resource} mean that I can add another doctor name into this array. So that I try to write { resource: doctors } to store the 3 doctors name. I think my code got something problem

Comment: @aminkeshavarzi Hope you can get my question

Comment: Why don't you add them in `doctorDetailList` instead of creating {source: doctors}. Mabye you should show the whole component so I could try to implement it in codesandbox or something.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BQseASHB5yYv-qzwX8QZR4JT8cO0pZdzSiYur__jaHc/edit?usp=sharing

@aminkeshavarzi Hi, my whole component with code has been attached this document. Thanks help me